# Hasura filtering Array relationships

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have users table and it has Array relationship with CustomerOrders i need to filter users based on CustomerOrders completion_date. It kind of works but when no date filters selected I need to show all users even those who does not have CustomerOrder if I add condition which ends in empty object {} it still considered as looking at thatCustomerOrder and I still get all users that have CustomerOrder.

My question is how to completely remove CustomerOrders Filter when inputs are empty?

variables

```
variables: {
        order_byUsers: { creationDate: 'desc' },
        whereUsers: {
          deleted_at: { _is_null: true }
          // CustomerOrders:
          //   fromDate && toDate
          //     ? {
          //         completion_date: {
          //           _gte: fromDate,
          //           _lte: toDate
          //         }
          //       }
          //     : {}
        },
        whereCustomerOrders: {
          completion_date:
            fromDate && toDate
              ? {
                  _gte: fromDate,
                  _lte: toDate
                }
              : {}
        },
        offsetUsers: state.pageSize * state.page,
        limitUsers: state.pageSize
      }
```

query

```
query GetUsersAnalysisGqlQuery(
    $whereUsers: User_bool_exp
    $whereCustomerOrders: CustomerOrder_bool_exp
    $order_byUsers: [User_order_by!]
    $limitUsers: Int
    $offsetUsers: Int
  ) {
    User(
      where: $whereUsers
      order_by: $order_byUsers
      limit: $limitUsers
      offset: $offsetUsers
    ) {
      id
      nameSurname
      email
      phone
      description
      blocked
      CustomerOrders(where: $whereCustomerOrders) {
        completion_date
      }
      CustomerOrderData {
        order_count
        amount
      }
    }
    User_aggregate(where: $whereUsers) {
      aggregate {
        count
      }
    }
  }
```

I also tried adding where variable for CustomerOrders ,but I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was this function

```
const getWhereUsersAnalysis = () => {
    let whereUsers: GQL_gen.Schema.User_Bool_Exp = {
      deleted_at: { _is_null: true }
    };

    if (fromDate && toDate) {
      whereUsers = {
        ...whereUsers,
        CustomerOrders: {
          completion_date: {
            _gte: fromDate,
            _lte: toDate
          }
        }
      };
    }

    return whereUsers;
  };
```

and i used it in variables like this

```
      variables: {
        order_byUsers: { creationDate: 'desc' },
        whereUsers: getWhereUsersAnalysis(),
        offsetUsers: state.pageSize * state.page,
        limitUsers: state.pageSize
      }
```